# How to stream screen desktop between two computer with gstreamer

Tags: shell, gstreamer

I want to stream the screen of my computer to and other using gstreamer and generate an rtsp adresse to use in Opencv.

I try few example to stream webcam between computers and it works properly:
    Command on the remote computer
    gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! "image/jpeg,width=1280, height=720,framerate=30/1" ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.17 port=5001

```
Command on the local computer
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

I saw some example which display current desktop but I don't now how to create rtsp adresse from it. When I just want to stream the current desktop I get error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc startx=1280 use-damage=0  ! "image/jpeg,width=1280, height=720,framerate=30/1" !    rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.17 port=5001
AVERTISSEMENT : pipeline erroné : impossible de connecter ximagesrc0 à rtpjpegpay0, ximagesrc0 n’accepte pas les majuscules image/jpeg, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1
```

Comment: Rtsp is not supported by Gstreamer. There is an seperate project on GitHub: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/. This will create a rtsp server, check the examples dir to get you started.